# How to restore form values when browsing back from href link?

Tags: html, href

I have a search page in my app that produces results containing links to other app pages (local only) when I type search terms into an `<input>` field - the usual search behavior. The anchors on the search page look like the following:

`"<a href='#/learn' target='_parent'>Go to the Learn page</a>"`

If I click the `Go to the Learn page` link, it navigates to the `Learn` page as expected. Hitting the browser back button, takes me back to the `Search` page, but the input field and search results are empty.

I do not want to open a new window, or tab. Instead, replace the window contents with the linked page, then go back to the results that got you there, and try a different link.

How to restore those values?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```js
localStorage.setItem('oldForm', [document.getElementById("input-id"), "..."]);

window.onload = function () {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input-id");
  input1.value = localStorage.getItem("oldForm")[1];
  //...
}
```

It should work

Comment: Hi DabDatBass - I appreciate the suggestion. I am looking into it now, but am having trouble getting the input ID from the Algolia searchBox widget. The widget embeds the <input>, and I've not yet found how to set or get it.

Comment: Hi DabDatBass - Your suggestion worked perfect. Thanks.